# I'm trying to call a class with constructors from a method in another class

Tags: c#

I am trying to call constructors from another class as i am trying to keep to OOP standard, Now i cant get the values back from the constructors.

The constructor:

```
namespace ContactForm.ContactFiles
{
   class Contact
   {

     //First name
     private string m_fName;
     //Last name
     private string m_lName;

     public Contact()
     {
     }

     public Contact(string FirstName)
         : this(FirstName, string.Empty)
     {
     }       

     public Contact(string FirstName, string LastName)
     {
         m_fName = FirstName;
         m_lName = LastName;
     }   

     public string Firstname
     {
         //First name
         get { return m_fName; }

         set { m_fName = value; }
     }

     public string Lastname
     {
         get { return m_lName; }

         set { m_lName = value; }
     }

     public string GetToStringItemsHeadings
     {
         get { return string.Format("{0,-20} {1, -20}", "First Name", "Last Name"); }
     }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         string strOut = string.Format("{0,-20} {1, -20}", m_fName, m_lName);
         return strOut;
     }         
}
```

I want to send in the values that are given in an Form(txtboxes) at a button_klick into this constructor in another class and i need to get hold of that strOut so i can use it and put it into a List and present that in another Form with a listbox. Thus keeping it to OOP standard, ?. If there is a better way to do it i am open for all and any ideas as its kind of new to me.

Comment: What constructors are you calling, and what values are you not getting back? Your code sample doesn't make this clear.

Comment: I want to call this Contact constructor from a winform, I have a form with 2 txt fields that after the user enters their first and last name klicks the button sending these two strings into the class above with my constructors that process the vaiables(lets say only first name was given) and then sends a created string from the variables sent into the constructor back out to yet another class. if thats even possible :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the button click, create an instance of the class, passing the values from the constructor:

```
var oContact = new Contact(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
```

then you can pass

```
oContact.ToString()
```

or the entire object to whatever code needs to use it.